# Combining forward and router for node-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I'm hosting multiple Node apps on one AWS instance.  I've been using apache with virtual hosts but want to only use Node.  The node-http-proxy looks like it will do the task but I can't get the forwarding to work with a proxy table.

Here's how proxy table is supposed to work:

```
var options = {
router: {
    'app1.website.com': 'localhost:7100',
    'app2.website.com': 'localhost:15110'
}
};

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);
```

I have app1 and app2 running on the instance and listening to 7100 and 15110 respectively but just using the router option doesn't allow for forwarding.

I can get just one to forward by using:

```
var options = {
forward: {
    port: 15110,
    host: 'localhost'
}
};

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(15110, 'localhost', options);
```

Any idea how to get the benefits of both?  The documentation says I can pass both 'forward' and 'router' through options but it's not clear how.

Comment: I spun up a new AWS instance, and followed Alan Hoffmeister's advice - everything works great now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? And what did you mean with "doesn't allow fowarding"? What node-http-proxy do is to internally proxy the request, not forward it :)

Comment: Tried using 127.0.0.1 but it didn't make a difference.  The 'router' options just doesn't work.  When I said forwarding I meant creating a reverse proxy to the other node servers running on ports 7100 and 15110 that aren't exposed to the client.